# What's happened to magic links?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

The comment shortcuts (magic links) don't seem to be working…

- Current comments

  [image]
- New comments

  [image]

What's happened?

Comment: Thanks - I saw that once and wrote it off as a slow internet connection as I was in a rush to get to another task. Seems like something more long term is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's fixed now…

[image]

---

Meta.SE: [Magical site hyperlinks broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215786/magical-site-hyperlinks-broken)